# How to add a panel to the properties region in the Image Editor?

Tags: python, interface, text-editor

How do I add a panel to the properties region in the image editor?
The code below is just a slight modification from the "ui_panel_simple.py" template. I changed the *bl_space_type* to be the text editor, and the *bl_region_type* to be *UI* which I thought would put it in the properties region, but it does not work.

```
import bpy

class HelloWorld(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Text Editor properties region"""
    bl_label = "Hello World"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world in the text editor!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorld)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorld)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Your code works for me, the label is displayed in the text editors property panel accessible by Ctrl-T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script works as written. The "problem" with the script is that it is putting the hello world in the text editor and not the image editor. [`bl_space_type`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_space_type#bpy.types.Panel.bl_space_type) takes:

`EMPTY`, `VIEW_3D`, `GRAPH_EDITOR`, `OUTLINER`, `PROPERTIES`, `FILE_BROWSER`, `IMAGE_EDITOR`, `INFO`, `SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, `TEXT_EDITOR`, `DOPESHEET_EDITOR`, `NLA_EDITOR`, `TIMELINE`, `NODE_EDITOR`, `LOGIC_EDITOR`, `CONSOLE`, `USER_PREFERENCES`

as accepted values, one for each window type in blender. The script in question has `TEXT_EDITOR` and not `IMAGE_EDITOR`.

```
import bpy

class HelloWorld(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Image Editor properties region"""
    bl_label = "Hello World"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world in the image editor!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorld)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorld)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```